# Find companies that offer AI solutions

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I have a social media app and currently, the feed is simply chronological. I need a personalized recommendation feed like Facebook, Instagram, TikTok, Netflix, Reddit etc. I mean there are many many smaller companies (like a few million downloads on the apps) that have such a feed as well.

So I guess there are companies providing solutions for this because it's a ​common need in apps.

I tried to find such a solution but I didn't find anything. I found tons of companies offering AI solutions for things like speech-to-text, chatbots, image stuff, or item recommendations in shops. But nothing for social media feeds.

Maybe I just don't know what to search for. I tried things like "AI solutions social media app", "feed solution social media", "ai feed social media" on Google search.

How do I find such stuff? Do I probably search for the wrong things?

(This is not an opinion-based question, it's not about what company offers the best solution for this. This would be indeed opinion-based, but I will make that decision myself later. It's only about generally finding companies that offer such solutions, which is a very important general thing. And it's certainly not opinion based to provide instructions to find AI solutions)

Comment: I recommend contacting computer science professors at some university. They could have PhD students working on such software. My opinion is that "companies offering such solutions" are called universities or research organizations. In Europe, there are also legal issues ([GDPR](https://gdpr-info.eu/) related). See also [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/). In Germany, contact your nearest [Fraunhofer](https://www.fraunhofer.de/en.html)

Comment: So, you are asking for a software that finds companies that offer AI solutions. And you want that like a news feed, so that you get new companies every day. Did I understand that correctly? What platform do you want to run this app on? How much do you want to pay?

Comment: Asking "How do I find such stuff?" and "Do I probably search for the wrong things?" is off-topic for this site, because those questions do not ask for a software product but they ask for handling of a known software product.